# CKEditor custom toolbar inline

Tags: ckeditor, fckeditor

I Want to use `Underline` in custom toolbar inline but it doesn't work while `bold` , `link` and `Italic` work as well.

```
 var cfg1 = {
        toolbar: [
            ['Source', '-', 'Bold','Italic', 'Underline']

        ]
    };
    CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
    CKEDITOR.inline('inputGozine1',cfg1);
```

How can i use `Underline` in inline toolbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check what you have in the `config.js` file? In standard and basic presets there is:

```
config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';
```

And this setting has higher priority than `config.toolbar`, so make sure to remove this line.